# The Media Query for My Radio Doesn’t Work for Apple Mobile Devices

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari

```css
@media (min-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:768px)
{ 
  .radio-button { 
    appearance: none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: black; padding: 6px 16px 5px 15px !important;
    margin: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    border-radius: 20px; 
    font-size: 16px; transition:
    background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease, border 0.3s ease; 
    position: relative; word-spacing: 10px; 
  }
}
```

My radio buttons are not styled with this CSS class with a media query on mobile Safari. What am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.